# minus sign in css rules

Tags: css, webfonts

Inspecting [medium.com](http://medium.com) css I noticed this rules:

```
--x-height-multiplier: 0.375;
--baseline-multiplier: 0.17;
```

what are those `--` before `x-height-multiplier`? What are these two rules? I tried to change them with no visible effect at all.

[image]

Comment: Those are [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) or custom properties.

Comment: Wow. Am I the only one that didn't find anything online by searching "--" ?

Comment: probably because search engines often treat - as query negation keyword for following word

Comment: yes, thought that too

Answer (score 1):

**Double dash represents CSS Variable.**
*Refer Link.*

[CSS Variable Spec at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

[CSS Variable Usage at CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/)

Comment: to be more precise in this particular case, it's about Custom Properties, `var()` is not used here

Comment: While declaring a CSS variable, `var()` is not required, it required only when using the variable

Comment: you dont' understand me :) ... the `--xx` alone is called a custom property and is used to define CSS variable ... read the first sentence of the link your provided : `They are set using custom property notation`